# Location updates not received during Fetch background mode

Tags: ios, background, location, fetch

I'm using [Selene](https://github.com/linkedin/Selene/) to schedule background fetch tasks.

During the fetch task I call `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and `startUpdatingLocation` on a `CLLocationManager` instance. When the fetch task is launched it can be seen on the status bar that location services are on, but the callback `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` is not called.

I have set the Required background modes to `fetch` and `location` and have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in plist file.

The code executed in the background fetch task works elsewhere and location updates are received when not in background task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was either due to not creating a UIBackgroundTask or using Selene. Using NS APIs solved the issue.